# Who owns the Golden Claw?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm trying to figure out who owns the Golden Claw so I can return it to complete the quest. I've killed the boss at the end and [acquired](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35893/why-cant-i-return-the-golden-claw-to-its-owner) the new shout, I just don't know who to return the claw to!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The claw belongs to [Lucian Valerius](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Lucan_Valerius):

[image: Lucian Valerius]

you can find him in Riverwood at his shop, the [*Riverwood Trader*](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Riverwood_Trader), in the center of town:

[image: Riverwood Trader]

In general, you can figure out what to do with a quest by tracking it in your quest journal: if you do that, you'll get a marker on your HUD's compass that'll lead you directly to where you need to go.

*(Images from the UESP)*