# How do I duplicate the writings on Calcelmo's wall?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

This is just one of a few quests that I have not finished because it basically leaves me confused to the point where I refuse to go back to them. When I click on the wall, it says I do not have the required item. But I don't understand what they're talking about by required item. How do I get it, equip it, and use it? Thanks.

Comment: You can see how to go through quests in [UESP](http://uesp.net/) (Wiki). For this quest, see http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Hard_Answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a piece of charcoal and a roll of paper to make a rubbing. They can be found in the area.

Comment: Do you also know how to find the owner of the golden claw??

Comment: The shop owner in Riverwood.

Comment: @David: There is a search in the upper-right:  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68729/who-owns-the-golden-claw