# How can I return the Golden Claw?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't I return the Golden Claw to its owner?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35893/why-cant-i-return-the-golden-claw-to-its-owner)

I have the golden claw, and killed the boss and looted it.  I am talking to Lucan Valerius now, and there is not an option to return it.  I am not sure what else I have to do now. How do I return it?

Comment: did you get the dragon shout off of the wall as well?

Answer (score 4):

First, make sure you opened the door in the Barrow that requires the claw. The barrow has two bosses, not one (Wounded Frostbite Spider + Draugr Overlord). This leads to an item required for the [Bleak Falls Barrow quest](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Bleak_Falls_Barrow_%28quest%29).

Then, if that doesn't work, you can also try Camilla who will also accept the claw.

If *that* doesn't work and you are on the PC, you can use Console Commands. Here are a few that I use if I get stuck on quests (`MS13` is the quest name in this case):

Type `setstage MS13 69`, which assigns the objective to return the claw, or to just skip right to having the quest complete: `setstage MS13 100` or `setstage MS13 200`.

Finally, if that doesn't work, try `resetquest MS13`followed by `StartQuest MS13`. You can use the `setstage` commands from there.